# Google script [merge duplicate cells into one]

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way that will combine duplicates into one....

The sheet currently looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RHY4.png)

Col A is employee ID, and each row relates to an entry of Leave. Some employees have more than one leave type which is why they are on a separate row.

The goal is to have one row per employee and somehow merge the Leave_Warnings into one cell per employee.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Straight from the horse mouth [Removing Duplicate Rows in a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the remove duplicate script is one that came across before but it does not help with merging data before removing.

Comment: (This is just and FYI for any others on similar journeys )
I have solved my duplicate issue with this formula: 
=ArrayFormula(split(concatenate(filter('Copy of LeaveCache_LVE'!$G$3:$G, 'Copy of LeaveCache_LVE'!$A$3:$A=A3)),"))"))

Answer (score 0):

This is just an FYI for any others on a similar journey

I have solved my duplicate issue with this formula:

=ArrayFormula(split(concatenate(filter('Copy of LeaveCache_LVE'!$G$3:$G, 'Copy of LeaveCache_LVE'!$A$3:$A=A3)),"))"))

Hope this helps someone else